# Set default brace(s) location in Xcode to be K&R style instead of 1TBS

Tags: xcode

I would like Xcode to stop formatting my Swift code with the opening brace on the same line (1TBS):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){

}
```

And instead put it on the next line (K&R style):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{

}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't possible, and it frustrates me to no end as well.

Comment: How can you write an XCode 9 extension to format the braces in the K&R style?

Comment: Your example of K&R is actually Allman style. K&R doesn't use braces unless needed and when needed it works like 1TBS.